# Chrome doesn't want to read the manifest.json (I am making a Chrome extension). Problem with "action"

Tags: html, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I was making a Chrome extension. It is time to launch the beta-testing. But suddenly Chrome started indicating an error (Syntax Error in line 12)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/GW5GT.png)(Sorry for Polish system language)

I wrote the manifest.json file as Chrome said (on developer.chrome.com, docs of Extensions), but it still shows a Syntax Error. Same in JSONLint. I can't figure out where is the error. Here is the code:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Librus Fajrant Mod",
  "description": "Mod to Librus writing 'Fajrant' under each last lesson of the day",
  "version": "1.0",
  "icons":{
      "16": "assets/icons/icon-16.jpg",
      "32": "assets/icons/icon-32.jpg",
      "48": "assets/icons/icon-48.jpg",
      "128": "assets/icons/icon-128.jpg"
  }
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
        "js":["scripts/content.js"],
        "matches": [
            "https://synergia.librus.pl/przegladaj_plan_lekcji"
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: A missing comma after the bracket above "action"